# Calculating expected bonus- what's wrong with my solution?

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification

An auto insurance company is implementing a new bonus system. In each month, if a policyholder does not have an accident, he or she will receive a $5 cashback bonus from the insurer. Among the 1000 policyholders, 400 are classified as low-risk drivers and 600 are classified as high-risk drivers. In each month, the probability of zero accidents for high-risk drivers is 0.8 and that for low-risk drivers is 0.9.

Calculate the expected bonus payment from the insurer to the 1000 policyholders in one year.

**The question is what's wrong with my (following) solution?**

Probability of zero accidents $= (0.8\times 0.6) + (0.90 \times 0.4) = 0.84$

Then, the expected payment is given by $$\sum_{x=1}^{12} (0.84^x) \times 1000 \times 5x$$

Comment: Each month is computed separately, so there is no need for $0.84^x$  There should also not be the $x$ at the end.  Please provide the logic behind your expressions.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: pls see my solution using the binomial rv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first line computes that the average number of accident free drivers in a month is $840$.  Those people receive $840\cdot 5=4200$ for the month.  Each month is the same, so the annual total is $12\cdot 4200=50400$

Comment: Which line are you referring to when you say "my first line"? I don't have 840 anywhere in my solution. I only have 0.84.

Comment: Your probability of zero accidents for one driver is $0.84$, so the expected number with no accidents is $840$

Answer (score 1):

OK here's the full solution:

Each risky customer is Binomial($0.8$), so the mean number of accident-free months is $\mathbf{E}X=np = 9.6$. Bonus is a function of this rv, $^Y=cX$, so $\mathbf{E}Y=9.6 \times 5 = 48$. Expectation is linear, so even if $Y$ are not independent, expected bonus for all risky customers, $S_1=\sum_{k=1}^{600}Y_k$ is:
$$
\mathbf{E}S_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{400}\mathbf{E}Y_k = 600 \times 48=28800
$$
Now, repeat this for non-risky customers,
$$
\mathbf{E}S_2 = 400 \times 0.9 \times 5 \times 12 = 21600
$$
In total,
$$
\mathbf{E}S = 28800+21600 = 50400
$$

Comment: Your approach is interesting, thanks for sharing.